# SFU with Kinesis video stream SDK js

Tags: webrtc, amazon-kinesis, mediasoup, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I built a React.js and Node.js app, inspired by [KVS example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc-sdk-js/tree/master/examples) .

It is working for a few participants, a Master can stream his webcam video & audio via WebRTC, and get every viewer webcam video. But we realized it won't be suitable for 50 people as the Master CPU and network increase over each viewer connection.
For every viewer a peerConnection is created with Master. We'd rather the Master to send his stream only once to a server (then sending it to viewers)

We would like to go for a SFU solution, would it be possible with the Javascript SDK ?
It is advised for the C SDK to use putMedia & GStreamer, is there an equivalent in javascript ?

I saw that mediaSoup could do the SFU part, could it be used with Kinesis ?

Comment: I have same problem.. only I didnt start yet.. hoping for answer. Can I ask how you got those results? I was not able to get more than one person with that KVS example

Comment: Each time an SDP offer is received on Master side, I update an object `peerConnectionById ` like in the example. But every event listener has to be set regarding this peerConnection as `peerConnectionById[remoteClientId].addEventListener( 'icecandidate', () => {})` for example.
If you keep track of all the remotePeers, you can loop on this object to see all the remote Viewers video.